# Opencart self developed module not sending emails to admin and store owner

Tags: php, module

A friend of mine and me developed an opencart payment module for a bank payment, meaning when you click confirm order, it takes you to the bank API. Everything works fine except for the fact that the following does not occur:

1. Payment does not effect on the dashboard
2. An emails is not received by the administrator even though we have used finfo@example.com and Finfo@example.com, I have included series of emails in the email field at the bottom of the page in the setting->mail tab->alert emails
3. All orders are being tagged as "Missing"
4. I tried cash on delivery and it worked fine (it sent emails)
5. I am on opencart 1.5.6 (boss theme goMarket)

Do you think setting an SMTP will do the magic? if yes, how can I get and set the SMTP from a GoDaddy hosted email acccount. I'd appreciate if you can help me with the solutions and where the errors may be coming from.

Comment: smtp settings in php only take effect if you're on a windows platform. otherwise mail() will use whatever mta is installed on the server. have you done any basic debugging yourself? check return values of mail() or whatever mail package you're using? checked mail server logs to see if the email is actually handed over? checked spam folders?

Comment: Hello Marc, Thanks for the response.what can i do to make sure my opencart receives an email and does not get tagged as missing?

Comment: Hello Marc,i have checked everywhere and its not found. Please which part of the codes handles the trapping of the products and register it on the dashboard. also, how do i edit the code to make sure it sends emails?

Comment: First you should check if there's any error on your site. And i think that is has something to do with the callback after the payment has finished ( it isn't completing the order, so no email will be send )

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a problem with the checkout/order controller.

Go to catalog/model/checkout/order.php and look into the confirm() function.
Something is probably making it fail because this is the function that handles both the database change from 'new' order to 'pending' as well as sending the email.

Under the confirm() function, look for $mail->send and simply comment out everything that has to do with sending the email. Then try to run a transaction. My hunch is that your problem is in the email sending syntax.

If that still doesn't work, you've got a bigger problem. 
Try to debug this function row by row while using var_dump() on the variables and seeing the results. After few times you'll be able to see when exactly the function breaks and take it from there...

Regarding your question about smtp - it could be your settings, but from my experience if your settings are not correct, it will not break your code execution. What you are experiencing sounds like a php syntax error to me.

One more thing - sometimes smtp will fail when using a local environment like mamp or wamp so make sure that (a) your mail settings are correct (b) that you deployed the site, even if it's a temporary address.

And one last thing - go to Admin->Settings->Error Logs and look for clues.

Hope this help!

Comment: Nice one at Yani unfortunately, there are no error in the log file and my fear is that there is a function that needs to send a status to opencart informing it whether each transaction is successful or not. that's where my problems lies. do you have anyway you can help?? you can send me an email to dolpaz02@yahoo.com

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the mail function and seeing what happens? Have you tried using var_dump() and debuging the lines? The confirm() function that I mentioned does exactly what you are looking for - it updates the database, sends the email and when returns successful, the view is changed to 'checkout/success'.

Comment: Hello Yani, you have been so instrumental to me..please how do i use the var_dump()..am relatively new to opencart and not much experience in php.where do i comment out the mail functions?? Please help me with steps..Thanks and God bless !